# Change CSS at a certain scroll level via jQuery doesn't work

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, scroll

The following jQuery code:

[Click here](http://jsfiddle.net/c9aXS/)

```
HTML:
<header class="header">
    <div class="navbar">   
        Hello
    </div>
</header>

CSS:
.header {
        background-color: black;
        height: 1000px;
        width: 300px;
        color: white;
        text-align: center;
        padding: 30px;
    }

.fixed .navbar{
    border: 10px solid red;
    position: fixed;
    background-color: white;
}

.navbar {
    background-color: blue;
    height: 50px;
    width: 300px;
    color: white;
}

JS:
$(window).scroll( function(){
        if($(window).scrollTop() > 200) $("header").addClass("fixed");
        else $("header").removeClass("fixed");    
    });
```

does work.

But when I add it to my homepage, I have to refresh the page for the "fixed" class to be added. But I want the class to be added live, while scrolling down, without the page having to be refreshed. This works in jsfiddle, why doesnt it work on my page?

My page: [Click here](http://nomisdesign.square7.ch)

Comment: try to add `$(function(){  /* your js code here */  });`.

Comment: @Aleksandar didn't try it, but it won't change anything. `$(window)` is defined before the DOM is ready.

Comment: Checking the console on your page gives the error: "undefined is not a function" on line 34 of index, which is the following line: `if($(window).scrollTop() > 50) $("header").addClass("fixed");`

Comment: @Aleksandar Now it's not working at all. Probably because function() is already included.

Comment: Your `$` symbole is beign overriden. Use `jQuery` instead of `$`

Comment: You have to include jquery in your website.

Comment: @BrunoQuintanaFleitas It is...

Comment: @BrunoQuintanaFleitas I did

Comment: yes, sorry, the problem is the overridden of $

Comment: @SimonMathewson Try what Karl-Andre said, or wrap it in a self-executing function, passing jQuery as an argument. `(function($) { /* Code here */ }(jQuery))`

Comment: @Karl-AndréGagnon Everywhere?

Comment: try to include jquery before noconflict.js, and wrap if and else with { }. maybe this is the problem

Comment: like this: (function($) {     $(window).on('scroll', function(){
        if($(this).scrollTop() > 200) $("header").addClass("fixed");
        else $("header").removeClass("fixed");    
    }); }(jQuery))

Comment: Ok, it actually works. Thanks for the fast answers guys, your are amazing :)

Comment: Now, tell us what the problem was? I'm very curious

Comment: @Aleksandar the $ symbols were overridden, so I had to replace them with "jQuery"

Comment: @BrunoQuintanaFleitas Exactly like that, but properly formatted ofcourse.

Comment: yeah, i forgot you are using noconflict.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As Karl-André said, your `$` object is being overwritten. To make your code work you can do either of the following:

Use the `jQuery` object:

```
jQuery(window).scroll( function(){
    if(jQuery(window).scrollTop() > 200) jQuery("header").addClass("fixed");
    else jQuery("header").removeClass("fixed");    
});
```

Or wrap everything in a self-executing function, passing the `jQuery` object as an argument:

```
(function($)
{
    $(window).scroll( function(){
        if($(window).scrollTop() > 200) $("header").addClass("fixed");
        else $("header").removeClass("fixed");    
    });
}(jQuery))
```

Answer (score 1):

Try using

```
$(function() {
    $(window).on('scroll', function(){
        if($(this).scrollTop() > 200) $("header").addClass("fixed");
        else $("header").removeClass("fixed");    
    });
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/c9aXS/2/

Comment: Look at the comments of the OP.